# How can I spot the sparse faulty elements when comparing two lists of strings and add them to a third list with a marker?

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to compare two lists of strings, namely *ordered_list* and *unordered_list* in which most of the items are following the same order. However, there are some sparse items breaking the order in either of the two lists between the chunks of exact same order.

I am looking to spot those items that are breaking the general equal order in both lists and add them to a third list, named *result_list*, marking them in the following manner:

- **Case 1:** if comparing both lists element-wise, there is an item in *ordered_list* that is not in this position within *unordered_list*, then add this element in *result_list* preceded by the ampersand (&).
- **Case 2:** if comparing both lists element-wise, there is an item in *unordered_list* that is not in this position within *ordered_list*, then add this element in *result_list* preceded by the percentage symbol (%).

The underlying idea of all this is that both lists have the exact same elements but some of them are in different positions between the lists, and I want to mark them in a third list by differentiating them from the non-faulty examples. I am struggling with this problem because I do not know how to make Python understand the words as such rather than the indexes of the items when doing the comparison. I need to spot the faulty words and only mark those ones.

Let me graphically show you the same problem applied to different lists, so that you can visualise what I am trying to explain. In the examples, the yellow-highlighted words are the ones following the same order in both lists (as you can see they are whole chunks of items being the same in both lists), the ones marked in red are the sparse breaking items in *unordered_list* that are not in *ordered_list* in that position, and the ones marked in green are the sparse breaking items in *ordered_list* that are not in *unordered_list* in that position. The expected resulting list is shown for each of the examples as well:

- [image: Example 1]
- [image: Example 2]
- [image: Example 3]

Here are the *ordered_list* and *unordered_list* for each of the examples:

```
# Example 1 lists

ordered_list = ['ñ', 'ña', 'ña', 'ñácara', 'ñacundá', 'ñacurutú', 'ñagaza', 'ñajo', 'ñame', 'ñamería', 'ñampeado', 'ñampearse', 'ñampí', 'ñaña', 'ñáñara', 'ñandú', 'ñandubay', 'ñandutí', 'ñanga', 'ñángara', 'ñangazo', 'ñango', 'ñangotado', 'ñangotarse', 'ñáñigo', 'ñañiguismo', 'ñaño', 'ñapa', 'ñapango', 'ñapindá', 'ñaque', 'ñaruso', 'ñata', 'ñatear', 'ñato', 'ñatuso', 'ñecla', 'ñeco', 'ñecudo', 'ñeembuqueño', 'ñeembuqueños', 'ñengo', 'ñeque', 'ñinga', 'ñipe', 'ñique', 'ñiquiñaque', 'ñire', 'ñisca', 'ñisñil', 'ñizca', 'ño', 'ñocha', 'ñoclo', 'ñoco', 'ñola', 'ñomblo', 'ñomblón', 'ñoña', 'ñoñería', 'ñoñez', 'ñongo', 'ñoño', 'ñoqui', 'ñor', 'ñora', 'ñorbo', 'ñu', 'ñublado', 'ñublar', 'ñublense', 'ñublino', 'ñublo', 'ñubloso', 'ñuco', 'ñudillo', 'ñudo', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco']

unordered_list = ['ñ', 'ña', 'ñácara', 'ñacundá', 'ñacurutú', 'ñagaza', 'ñajo', 'ñame', 'ñamería', 'ñampeado', 'ñampearse', 'ñampí', 'ñandú', 'ñandubay', 'ñandutí', 'ñanga', 'ñángara', 'ñangazo', 'ñango', 'ñangotado', 'ñangotarse', 'ñaña', 'ñáñara', 'ñáñigo', 'ñañiguismo', 'ñaño', 'ñapa', 'ñapango', 'ñapindá', 'ñaque', 'ñaruso', 'ñata', 'ñatear', 'ñato', 'ñatuso', 'ñecla', 'ñeco', 'ñecudo', 'ñeembuqueño', 'ña', 'ñeembuqueños', 'ñengo', 'ñeque', 'ñinga', 'ñipe', 'ñique', 'ñiquiñaque', 'ñire', 'ñisca', 'ñisñil', 'ñizca', 'ño', 'ñocha', 'ñoclo', 'ñoco', 'ñola', 'ñomblo', 'ñomblón', 'ñongo', 'ñoñería', 'ñoñez', 'ñoña', 'ñoño', 'ñoqui', 'ñor', 'ñora', 'ñorbo', 'ñu', 'ñublado', 'ñublar', 'ñublense', 'ñublino', 'ñublo', 'ñubloso', 'ñuco', 'ñudillo', 'ñudo', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco']

# Example 2 lists

ordered_list = ['k', 'ka', 'kabuki', 'kafkiano', 'káiser', 'kaki', 'kaki', 'kalmuko', 'kalmukos', 'kamikaze', 'kamikaze', 'kan', 'kanindeyuense', 'kanindeyuenses', 'kanjobal', 'kanjobal', 'kanjobales', 'kantiano', 'kantismo', 'kappa', 'karaoke', 'kárate', 'karateca', 'karma', 'karst', 'kárstico', 'kart', 'kartismo', 'kastila', 'katipunan', 'katiuska', 'kavakava', 'kayak', 'kazajo', 'kazako', 'kebab', 'kéfir', 'kelvin', 'kendo', 'keniano', 'keniata', 'kerigma', 'kermes', 'kermés', 'kerosén', 'kétchup', 'kevlar', 'kibutz', 'kif', 'kiko', 'kikuyo', 'kiliárea', 'kílim', 'kilo', 'kilobyte', 'kilocaloría', 'kilociclo', 'kilográmetro', 'kilogramo', 'kilogramo', 'kilohercio', 'kilolitro', 'kilometraje', 'kilometrar', 'kilométrico', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', 'kilómetro', 'kilopondio', 'kilotón', 'kilovatio', 'kilovoltio', 'kimono', 'kinder', 'kindergarten', 'kinesiología', 'kinesiología', 'kinesiológico', 'kinesiólogo', 'kinesioterapia', 'kinesioterápico', 'kínésis', 'kinesiterapia', 'kinesiterápico', 'kion', 'kiosco', 'kiosquero', 'kipá', 'kirguís', 'kirguiso', 'kirguiz', 'kirguizio', 'kirguizo', 'kiribatiano', 'kirie', 'kirieleisón', 'kirsch', 'kit', 'kitsch', 'kivi', 'kívnoic', 'kiwi', 'klistrón', 'koala', 'kodzito', 'kohl', 'kohol', 'koiné', 'kopek', 'kosovar', 'krausismo', 'krausista', 'kremlin', 'kremlinología', 'kremlinólogo', 'kril', 'kriptón', 'kris', 'kufiya', 'kurchatovio', 'kurdo', 'kuwaití']

unordered_list = ['k', 'ka', 'kabuki', 'kafkiano', 'káiser', 'kaki', 'kaki', 'kalmuko', 'kalmukos', 'kamikaze', 'kamikaze', 'kan', 'kanindeyuense', 'kanindeyuenses', 'kanjobal', 'kanjobales', 'kanjobal', 'kantiano', 'kantismo', 'kappa', 'karaoke', 'kárate', 'karateca', 'karma', 'karst', 'kárstico', 'kart', 'kartismo', 'kastila', 'katipunan', 'katiuska', 'kavakava', 'kayak', 'kazajo', 'kazako', 'kebab', 'kéfir', 'kelvin', 'kendo', 'keniano', 'keniata', 'kerigma', 'kermes', 'kermés', 'kerosén', 'kétchup', 'kevlar', 'kibutz', 'kif', 'kiko', 'kikuyo', 'kiliárea', 'kílim', 'kilo', 'kilobyte', 'kilocaloría', 'kilociclo', 'kilográmetro', 'kilogramo', 'kilogramo', 'kilohercio', 'kilolitro', 'kilometraje', 'kilometrar', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', 'kilopondio', 'kilotón', 'kilovatio', 'kilovoltio', 'kimono', 'kinder', 'kindergarten', 'kinesiología', 'kinesiológico', 'kinesiólogo', 'kinesiología', 'kinesioterapia', 'kívnoic', 'kínésis', 'kinesioterápico', 'kinesiterapia', 'kinesiterápico', 'kion', 'kiosco', 'kiosquero', 'kipá', 'kirguís', 'kirguiso', 'kirguiz', 'kirguizio', 'kirguizo', 'kiribatiano', 'kirie', 'kirieleisón', 'kirsch', 'kit', 'kitsch', 'kivi', 'kiwi', 'klistrón', 'koala', 'kodzito', 'kohl', 'kohol', 'koiné', 'kopek', 'kosovar', 'krausismo', 'krausista', 'kremlin', 'kremlinología', 'kremlinólogo', 'kril', 'kriptón', 'kris', 'kufiya', 'kurchatovio', 'kurdo', 'kuwaití']

# Example 3 lists

ordered_list = ['a', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'ábaco', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'ábax', 'aceite', 'aceite', 'ancianos', 'ár', 'arquitrabe', 'arquitrabe']

unordered_list = ['a', 'ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'abadía', 'ábaco', 'ábax', 'arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe']
```

And here is the code that I have been trying so far, which is not working as it does not find and mark the right elements I need:

```py
# Initialize the result_list_one
result_list = []

# Iterate through the ordered_list
for i in range(len(ordered_list)):
    # Check if the current element in ordered_list is equal to the corresponding element in unordered_list
    if ordered_list[i] == unordered_list[i]:
        result_list.append(ordered_list[i])
    else:
        # If not equal, add the element from ordered_list preceded by '&' and the element from unordered_list preceded by '%'
        result_list.append(f"%{ordered_list[i]}")
        result_list.append(f"&{unordered_list[i]}")

# Print the result_list
print(result_list)
```

Finally, here are the lists that I am expecting to get as *result_list*:

```py
# Example 1 result_list

result_list = ['ñ', 'ña', '&ña', 'ñácara', 'ñacundá', 'ñacurutú', 'ñagaza', 'ñajo', 'ñame', 'ñamería', 'ñampeado', 'ñampearse', 'ñampí', '&ñaña', '&ñáñara','ñandú', 'ñandubay', 'ñandutí', 'ñanga', 'ñángara', 'ñangazo', 'ñango', 'ñangotado', 'ñangotarse', '%ñaña', '%ñáñara', 'ñáñigo', 'ñañiguismo', 'ñaño', 'ñapa', 'ñapango', 'ñapindá', 'ñaque', 'ñaruso', 'ñata', 'ñatear', 'ñato', 'ñatuso', 'ñecla', 'ñeco', 'ñecudo', 'ñeembuqueño', '%ña', 'ñeembuqueños', 'ñengo', 'ñeque', 'ñinga', 'ñipe', 'ñique', 'ñiquiñaque', 'ñire', 'ñisca', 'ñisñil', 'ñizca', 'ño', 'ñocha', 'ñoclo', 'ñoco', 'ñola', 'ñomblo', 'ñomblón', '&ñoña', '%ñongo', 'ñoñería', 'ñoñez', '%ñoña', '&ñongo', 'ñoño', 'ñoqui', 'ñor', 'ñora', 'ñorbo', 'ñu', 'ñublado', 'ñublar', 'ñublense', 'ñublino', 'ñublo', 'ñubloso', 'ñuco', 'ñudillo', 'ñudo', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco']

# Example 2 result_list

result_list = ['k', 'ka', 'kabuki', 'kafkiano', 'káiser', 'kaki', 'kaki', 'kalmuko', 'kalmukos', 'kamikaze', 'kamikaze', 'kan', 'kanindeyuense', 'kanindeyuenses', 'kanjobal', '%kanjobales', 'kanjobal', '&kanjobales', 'kantiano', 'kantismo', 'kappa', 'karaoke', 'kárate', 'karateca', 'karma', 'karst', 'kárstico', 'kart', 'kartismo', 'kastila', 'katipunan', 'katiuska', 'kavakava', 'kayak', 'kazajo', 'kazako', 'kebab', 'kéfir', 'kelvin', 'kendo', 'keniano', 'keniata', 'kerigma', 'kermes', 'kermés', 'kerosén', 'kétchup', 'kevlar', 'kibutz', 'kif', 'kiko', 'kikuyo', 'kiliárea', 'kílim', 'kilo', 'kilobyte', 'kilocaloría', 'kilociclo', 'kilográmetro', 'kilogramo', 'kilogramo', 'kilohercio', 'kilolitro', 'kilometraje', 'kilometrar', 'kilométrico', '%kilómetro', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', '&kilómetro', 'kilopondio', 'kilotón', 'kilovatio', 'kilovoltio', 'kimono', 'kinder', 'kindergarten', 'kinesiología', '%kinesiológico', '%kinesiólogo', 'kinesiología', '&kinesiológico', '&kinesiólogo', 'kinesioterapia', '%kívnoic', '%kínésis', 'kinesioterápico', '&kínésis', 'kinesiterapia', 'kinesiterápico', 'kion', 'kiosco', 'kiosquero', 'kipá', 'kirguís', 'kirguiso', 'kirguiz', 'kirguizio', 'kirguizo', 'kiribatiano', 'kirie', 'kirieleisón', 'kirsch', 'kit', 'kitsch', 'kivi', '&kívnoic', 'kiwi', 'klistrón', 'koala', 'kodzito', 'kohl', 'kohol', 'koiné', 'kopek', 'kosovar', 'krausismo', 'krausista', 'kremlin', 'kremlinología', 'kremlinólogo', 'kril', 'kriptón', 'kris', 'kufiya', 'kurchatovio', 'kurdo', 'kuwaití']

# Example 3 result_list

result_list = ['a', '$ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', '$ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', '$aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', '$abadía', 'ábaco', '$ábax', '$arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe']
```

I am looking for a code that can be applied to the three examples and to any other comparison of lists having the same issues. I hope you can help me, as I feel pretty lost.

Comment: @user19077881 thanks for your answer. This is why I say "I do not know how to make Python understand the words as such rather than the indexes". Ñácara is working correctly in both lists, but what is making it have a different index in both lists is the previous item 'ña', which is present in ordered_list but not in unordered_list. So this ña is breaking the order and so marked with the ampersand.

Comment: @user19077881 this is what I am trying to identify: the words that alter the indexes between both lists (either because they are in ordered_list but not in unordered_list, or vice versa). I posted the pictures because I thought it was going to be understood better graphically, buy maybe I have confused you more by doing this (?).

Comment: I don't think an index approach is the way to go. Since the two Lists contain all the same elements then the **%** and **&** marked words must occur in pairs. So maybe this is an approach: you find the words out-of-order in unordered_list by comparing one word with the next, mark these and then mark the same words in ordered_list. Then form the result_list from the two marked Lists. As the words use accented characters a locale-based sorting key/method would need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it easier to follow your logic and made it so the lists print out like this:

```
o_list = ['ñ', 'ña', 'ña', 'ñácara',
u_list = ['ñ', 'ña', '  ', 'ñácara',
r_list = ['ñ', 'ña', '&ña', 'ñácara',
```

Here's the code:

```
# Example 1 lists
ordered_list_1 =   ['ñ', 'ña', 'ña',  'ñácara', 'ñacundá', 'ñacurutú', 'ñagaza', 'ñajo', 'ñame', 'ñamería', 'ñampeado', 'ñampearse', 'ñampí', 'ñaña', 'ñáñara',  'ñandú', 'ñandubay', 'ñandutí', 'ñanga', 'ñángara', 'ñangazo', 'ñango', 'ñangotado', 'ñangotarse',                     'ñáñigo', 'ñañiguismo', 'ñaño', 'ñapa', 'ñapango', 'ñapindá', 'ñaque', 'ñaruso', 'ñata', 'ñatear', 'ñato', 'ñatuso', 'ñecla', 'ñeco', 'ñecudo', 'ñeembuqueño',        'ñeembuqueños', 'ñengo', 'ñeque', 'ñinga', 'ñipe', 'ñique', 'ñiquiñaque', 'ñire', 'ñisca', 'ñisñil', 'ñizca', 'ño', 'ñocha', 'ñoclo', 'ñoco', 'ñola', 'ñomblo', 'ñomblón', 'ñoña',            'ñoñería', 'ñoñez',          'ñongo',  'ñoño', 'ñoqui', 'ñor', 'ñora', 'ñorbo', 'ñu', 'ñublado', 'ñublar', 'ñublense', 'ñublino', 'ñublo', 'ñubloso', 'ñuco', 'ñudillo', 'ñudo', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco']
unordered_list_1 = ['ñ', 'ña',        'ñácara', 'ñacundá', 'ñacurutú', 'ñagaza', 'ñajo', 'ñame', 'ñamería', 'ñampeado', 'ñampearse', 'ñampí',                    'ñandú', 'ñandubay', 'ñandutí', 'ñanga', 'ñángara', 'ñangazo', 'ñango', 'ñangotado', 'ñangotarse', 'ñaña',  'ñáñara',  'ñáñigo', 'ñañiguismo', 'ñaño', 'ñapa', 'ñapango', 'ñapindá', 'ñaque', 'ñaruso', 'ñata', 'ñatear', 'ñato', 'ñatuso', 'ñecla', 'ñeco', 'ñecudo', 'ñeembuqueño', 'ña',  'ñeembuqueños', 'ñengo', 'ñeque', 'ñinga', 'ñipe', 'ñique', 'ñiquiñaque', 'ñire', 'ñisca', 'ñisñil', 'ñizca', 'ño', 'ñocha', 'ñoclo', 'ñoco', 'ñola', 'ñomblo', 'ñomblón',          'ñongo',  'ñoñería', 'ñoñez', 'ñoña',            'ñoño', 'ñoqui', 'ñor', 'ñora', 'ñorbo', 'ñu', 'ñublado', 'ñublar', 'ñublense', 'ñublino', 'ñublo', 'ñubloso', 'ñuco', 'ñudillo', 'ñudo', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco']
result_list_1 =    ['ñ', 'ña', '&ña', 'ñácara', 'ñacundá', 'ñacurutú', 'ñagaza', 'ñajo', 'ñame', 'ñamería', 'ñampeado', 'ñampearse', 'ñampí', '&ñaña', '&ñáñara','ñandú', 'ñandubay', 'ñandutí', 'ñanga', 'ñángara', 'ñangazo', 'ñango', 'ñangotado', 'ñangotarse', '%ñaña', '%ñáñara', 'ñáñigo', 'ñañiguismo', 'ñaño', 'ñapa', 'ñapango', 'ñapindá', 'ñaque', 'ñaruso', 'ñata', 'ñatear', 'ñato', 'ñatuso', 'ñecla', 'ñeco', 'ñecudo', 'ñeembuqueño', '%ña', 'ñeembuqueños', 'ñengo', 'ñeque', 'ñinga', 'ñipe', 'ñique', 'ñiquiñaque', 'ñire', 'ñisca', 'ñisñil', 'ñizca', 'ño', 'ñocha', 'ñoclo', 'ñoco', 'ñola', 'ñomblo', 'ñomblón', '&ñoña', '%ñongo', 'ñoñería', 'ñoñez', '%ñoña', '&ñongo', 'ñoño', 'ñoqui', 'ñor', 'ñora', 'ñorbo', 'ñu', 'ñublado', 'ñublar', 'ñublense', 'ñublino', 'ñublo', 'ñubloso', 'ñuco', 'ñudillo', 'ñudo', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco']
# Example 2 lists
ordered_list_2 = ['k', 'ka', 'kabuki', 'kafkiano', 'káiser', 'kaki', 'kaki', 'kalmuko', 'kalmukos', 'kamikaze', 'kamikaze', 'kan', 'kanindeyuense', 'kanindeyuenses', 'kanjobal', 'kanjobal', 'kanjobales', 'kantiano', 'kantismo', 'kappa', 'karaoke', 'kárate', 'karateca', 'karma', 'karst', 'kárstico', 'kart', 'kartismo', 'kastila', 'katipunan', 'katiuska', 'kavakava', 'kayak', 'kazajo', 'kazako', 'kebab', 'kéfir', 'kelvin', 'kendo', 'keniano', 'keniata', 'kerigma', 'kermes', 'kermés', 'kerosén', 'kétchup', 'kevlar', 'kibutz', 'kif', 'kiko', 'kikuyo', 'kiliárea', 'kílim', 'kilo', 'kilobyte', 'kilocaloría', 'kilociclo', 'kilográmetro', 'kilogramo', 'kilogramo', 'kilohercio', 'kilolitro', 'kilometraje', 'kilometrar', 'kilométrico', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', 'kilómetro', 'kilopondio', 'kilotón', 'kilovatio', 'kilovoltio', 'kimono', 'kinder', 'kindergarten', 'kinesiología', 'kinesiología', 'kinesiológico', 'kinesiólogo', 'kinesioterapia', 'kinesioterápico', 'kínésis', 'kinesiterapia', 'kinesiterápico', 'kion', 'kiosco', 'kiosquero', 'kipá', 'kirguís', 'kirguiso', 'kirguiz', 'kirguizio', 'kirguizo', 'kiribatiano', 'kirie', 'kirieleisón', 'kirsch', 'kit', 'kitsch', 'kivi', 'kívnoic', 'kiwi', 'klistrón', 'koala', 'kodzito', 'kohl', 'kohol', 'koiné', 'kopek', 'kosovar', 'krausismo', 'krausista', 'kremlin', 'kremlinología', 'kremlinólogo', 'kril', 'kriptón', 'kris', 'kufiya', 'kurchatovio', 'kurdo', 'kuwaití']
unordered_list_2 = ['k', 'ka', 'kabuki', 'kafkiano', 'káiser', 'kaki', 'kaki', 'kalmuko', 'kalmukos', 'kamikaze', 'kamikaze', 'kan', 'kanindeyuense', 'kanindeyuenses', 'kanjobal', 'kanjobales', 'kanjobal', 'kantiano', 'kantismo', 'kappa', 'karaoke', 'kárate', 'karateca', 'karma', 'karst', 'kárstico', 'kart', 'kartismo', 'kastila', 'katipunan', 'katiuska', 'kavakava', 'kayak', 'kazajo', 'kazako', 'kebab', 'kéfir', 'kelvin', 'kendo', 'keniano', 'keniata', 'kerigma', 'kermes', 'kermés', 'kerosén', 'kétchup', 'kevlar', 'kibutz', 'kif', 'kiko', 'kikuyo', 'kiliárea', 'kílim', 'kilo', 'kilobyte', 'kilocaloría', 'kilociclo', 'kilográmetro', 'kilogramo', 'kilogramo', 'kilohercio', 'kilolitro', 'kilometraje', 'kilometrar', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', 'kilopondio', 'kilotón', 'kilovatio', 'kilovoltio', 'kimono', 'kinder', 'kindergarten', 'kinesiología', 'kinesiológico', 'kinesiólogo', 'kinesiología', 'kinesioterapia', 'kívnoic', 'kínésis', 'kinesioterápico', 'kinesiterapia', 'kinesiterápico', 'kion', 'kiosco', 'kiosquero', 'kipá', 'kirguís', 'kirguiso', 'kirguiz', 'kirguizio', 'kirguizo', 'kiribatiano', 'kirie', 'kirieleisón', 'kirsch', 'kit', 'kitsch', 'kivi', 'kiwi', 'klistrón', 'koala', 'kodzito', 'kohl', 'kohol', 'koiné', 'kopek', 'kosovar', 'krausismo', 'krausista', 'kremlin', 'kremlinología', 'kremlinólogo', 'kril', 'kriptón', 'kris', 'kufiya', 'kurchatovio', 'kurdo', 'kuwaití']
result_list_2 = ['k', 'ka', 'kabuki', 'kafkiano', 'káiser', 'kaki', 'kaki', 'kalmuko', 'kalmukos', 'kamikaze', 'kamikaze', 'kan', 'kanindeyuense', 'kanindeyuenses', 'kanjobal', '%kanjobales', 'kanjobal', '&kanjobales', 'kantiano', 'kantismo', 'kappa', 'karaoke', 'kárate', 'karateca', 'karma', 'karst', 'kárstico', 'kart', 'kartismo', 'kastila', 'katipunan', 'katiuska', 'kavakava', 'kayak', 'kazajo', 'kazako', 'kebab', 'kéfir', 'kelvin', 'kendo', 'keniano', 'keniata', 'kerigma', 'kermes', 'kermés', 'kerosén', 'kétchup', 'kevlar', 'kibutz', 'kif', 'kiko', 'kikuyo', 'kiliárea', 'kílim', 'kilo', 'kilobyte', 'kilocaloría', 'kilociclo', 'kilográmetro', 'kilogramo', 'kilogramo', 'kilohercio', 'kilolitro', 'kilometraje', 'kilometrar', 'kilométrico', '%kilómetro', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', '&kilómetro', 'kilopondio', 'kilotón', 'kilovatio', 'kilovoltio', 'kimono', 'kinder', 'kindergarten', 'kinesiología', '%kinesiológico', '%kinesiólogo', 'kinesiología', '&kinesiológico', '&kinesiólogo', 'kinesioterapia', '%kívnoic', '%kínésis', 'kinesioterápico', '&kínésis', 'kinesiterapia', 'kinesiterápico', 'kion', 'kiosco', 'kiosquero', 'kipá', 'kirguís', 'kirguiso', 'kirguiz', 'kirguizio', 'kirguizo', 'kiribatiano', 'kirie', 'kirieleisón', 'kirsch', 'kit', 'kitsch', 'kivi', '&kívnoic', 'kiwi', 'klistrón', 'koala', 'kodzito', 'kohl', 'kohol', 'koiné', 'kopek', 'kosovar', 'krausismo', 'krausista', 'kremlin', 'kremlinología', 'kremlinólogo', 'kril', 'kriptón', 'kris', 'kufiya', 'kurchatovio', 'kurdo', 'kuwaití']
# Example 3 lists
ordered_list_3 = ['a', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'ábaco', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'ábax', 'aceite', 'aceite', 'ancianos', 'ár', 'arquitrabe', 'arquitrabe']
unordered_list_3 = ['a', 'ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'abadía', 'ábaco', 'ábax', 'arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe']
result_list_3 = ['a', '$ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', '$ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', '$aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', '$abadía', 'ábaco', '$ábax', '$arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe']

# Please change the numbers at the end of ordered_list1, unordered_list1, result_list1 to reflect the 3 examples on the next 3 lines
o_list = orig_o_list = ordered_list_1
u_list = orig_u_list = unordered_list_1
e_list = result_list_1 # expected outcome
r_list = [] # result list

def next_index_in_o_list(o_list, u_word, i): 
    for index, o_word in enumerate(o_list[i:], i):
        if u_word == o_word: return index
    return -1
def next_index_in_u_list(u_list, o_word, i):
    for index, u_word in enumerate(u_list[i:], i):
        if o_word == u_word: return index
    return -1
def which_list_to_shift(i_u_in_o, i_o_in_u):
    if i_u_in_o < 0 and i_o_in_u < 0: return 2 # shift unordered list
    if i_u_in_o == i_o_in_u: return 2 # shift ordered list
    if i_o_in_u < 0: return 2 # shift unordered list
    if i_u_in_o < 0: return 1 # shift ordered list 
    if i_u_in_o > i_o_in_u: return 1 # shift ordered list
    else: return 2 # shift unordered list

i = 0
while True:
    if o_list[i] != u_list[i]: # if words don't match check which list to shift
        i_next_uword_in_olist = next_index_in_o_list(o_list, u_list[i], i+1) # e.g. where does 'ñácara' from the unordered_list1 [at index 2] next appear in the appear in the ordered_list1?
        i_next_oword_in_ulist = next_index_in_u_list(u_list, o_list[i], i+1) # e.g. where does 'ña' from the ordered_list1 [at index 2] next appear in the appear in the unordered_list1?
        if which_list_to_shift(i_next_uword_in_olist, i_next_oword_in_ulist) == 1: # shift ordered list
            o_list.insert(i, ' ' * len(u_list[i]))
            r_list.append('%' + u_list[i])
        else: # shift unordered list
            u_list.insert(i, ' ' * len(o_list[i]))
            r_list.append('&' + o_list[i])
    else: r_list.append(o_list[i]) # strings are equal
    i += 1
    if i > len(o_list)-1 or i > len(u_list)-1: break

print(f'o_list = {o_list}')
print(f'u_list = {u_list}')
print(f'i={[str(x)+" "*(len(u_list[x])-len(str(x))) for x in range(0, i)]}') # print helper index lists for easier referencing of differences
print(f'r_list = {r_list}')
print(f'e_list = {e_list}')
print(f'i={[str(x)+" "*(len(r_list[x])-len(str(x))) for x in range(0, i)]}')
for i, o_word in enumerate(r_list): # compare results with expected
    if e_list[i] != r_list[i]:
        print(f'i={i} r_list[i] = {r_list[i]} != e_list[i] = {e_list[i]} (actual result does not match expected)')
```

I get mostly matching results but there are differences compared to the results you posted. Perhaps you could look into a few cases and make adjustments. For example, in Example 1, you chose a word from the ordered list to go into the results list first on one mismatch, but then in a similar mismatch later on you chose the word from the unordered list first, and I'm not sure why.
[image: Screenprint of the example above]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast method (250ms for 100K elements in each list) that uses dicts for lookup of positions (no need for many `str.index()` calls). Elements are converted to tuples with an occurrence number to disambiguate duplicates (e.g., `('ña', 0)` vs. `('ña', 1)`) and those are the keys of dicts that identify the position in each list. The implementation uses generators (i.e., `ag = enumerate(a)`) for concision, and also to ensure a strictly forward progress on each list. The idea is to look up the distance where an item is found in the other list and choose the closest. When the distances are the same, it prioritizes `ordered_list` by default (`breaktie=0`), but that can be changed with `breaktie=1`. In the examples, as noted by others in comments and other answers, it seems there are some inconsistencies on that front.

```py
from operator import le, lt

def todict(lst):
    d = {}
    cnt = {}
    for i, e in enumerate(lst):
        cnt[e] = (k := cnt.get(e, 0)) + 1
        d[e, k] = i
    return d

def merge(a, b, breaktie=0):
    nmax = 1 << 31  # arbitrary large value (longer than longest list)
    op = le if breaktie == 0 else lt
    da, db = todict(a), todict(b)
    ag, bg = enumerate(da), enumerate(db)
    i, ai = next(ag)
    j, bj = next(bg)
    try:
        while True:
            if ai == bj:
                yield ai[0]
                i, ai = next(ag)
                j, bj = next(bg)
                continue
            bdist = db.get(ai, -1) - j  # ai is bdist positions further in b list
            bdist = bdist if bdist > 0 else nmax
            adist = da.get(bj, -1) - i  # bj is adist positions further in a list
            adist = adist if adist > 0 else nmax
            if op(adist, bdist):
                yield f'&{ai[0]}'
                i, ai = next(ag)
            else:
                yield f'%{bj[0]}'
                j, bj = next(bg)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    for ai in ag:
        yield f'&{ai[0]}'
    for bi in bg:
        yield f'%{bj[0]}'
```

We collect all the OP's examples in a list of 3-tuples (ordered, unordered, expected_result):

```py
examples = [(
    ['ñ', 'ña', 'ña', 'ñácara', 'ñacundá', 'ñacurutú', 'ñagaza', 'ñajo', 'ñame', 'ñamería', 'ñampeado', 'ñampearse', 'ñampí', 'ñaña', 'ñáñara', 'ñandú', 'ñandubay', 'ñandutí', 'ñanga', 'ñángara', 'ñangazo', 'ñango', 'ñangotado', 'ñangotarse', 'ñáñigo', 'ñañiguismo', 'ñaño', 'ñapa', 'ñapango', 'ñapindá', 'ñaque', 'ñaruso', 'ñata', 'ñatear', 'ñato', 'ñatuso', 'ñecla', 'ñeco', 'ñecudo', 'ñeembuqueño', 'ñeembuqueños', 'ñengo', 'ñeque', 'ñinga', 'ñipe', 'ñique', 'ñiquiñaque', 'ñire', 'ñisca', 'ñisñil', 'ñizca', 'ño', 'ñocha', 'ñoclo', 'ñoco', 'ñola', 'ñomblo', 'ñomblón', 'ñoña', 'ñoñería', 'ñoñez', 'ñongo', 'ñoño', 'ñoqui', 'ñor', 'ñora', 'ñorbo', 'ñu', 'ñublado', 'ñublar', 'ñublense', 'ñublino', 'ñublo', 'ñubloso', 'ñuco', 'ñudillo', 'ñudo', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco'],
    ['ñ', 'ña', 'ñácara', 'ñacundá', 'ñacurutú', 'ñagaza', 'ñajo', 'ñame', 'ñamería', 'ñampeado', 'ñampearse', 'ñampí', 'ñandú', 'ñandubay', 'ñandutí', 'ñanga', 'ñángara', 'ñangazo', 'ñango', 'ñangotado', 'ñangotarse', 'ñaña', 'ñáñara', 'ñáñigo', 'ñañiguismo', 'ñaño', 'ñapa', 'ñapango', 'ñapindá', 'ñaque', 'ñaruso', 'ñata', 'ñatear', 'ñato', 'ñatuso', 'ñecla', 'ñeco', 'ñecudo', 'ñeembuqueño', 'ña', 'ñeembuqueños', 'ñengo', 'ñeque', 'ñinga', 'ñipe', 'ñique', 'ñiquiñaque', 'ñire', 'ñisca', 'ñisñil', 'ñizca', 'ño', 'ñocha', 'ñoclo', 'ñoco', 'ñola', 'ñomblo', 'ñomblón', 'ñongo', 'ñoñería', 'ñoñez', 'ñoña', 'ñoño', 'ñoqui', 'ñor', 'ñora', 'ñorbo', 'ñu', 'ñublado', 'ñublar', 'ñublense', 'ñublino', 'ñublo', 'ñubloso', 'ñuco', 'ñudillo', 'ñudo', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco'],
    ['ñ', 'ña', '&ña', 'ñácara', 'ñacundá', 'ñacurutú', 'ñagaza', 'ñajo', 'ñame', 'ñamería', 'ñampeado', 'ñampearse', 'ñampí', '&ñaña', '&ñáñara','ñandú', 'ñandubay', 'ñandutí', 'ñanga', 'ñángara', 'ñangazo', 'ñango', 'ñangotado', 'ñangotarse', '%ñaña', '%ñáñara', 'ñáñigo', 'ñañiguismo', 'ñaño', 'ñapa', 'ñapango', 'ñapindá', 'ñaque', 'ñaruso', 'ñata', 'ñatear', 'ñato', 'ñatuso', 'ñecla', 'ñeco', 'ñecudo', 'ñeembuqueño', '%ña', 'ñeembuqueños', 'ñengo', 'ñeque', 'ñinga', 'ñipe', 'ñique', 'ñiquiñaque', 'ñire', 'ñisca', 'ñisñil', 'ñizca', 'ño', 'ñocha', 'ñoclo', 'ñoco', 'ñola', 'ñomblo', 'ñomblón', '&ñoña', '%ñongo', 'ñoñería', 'ñoñez', '%ñoña', '&ñongo', 'ñoño', 'ñoqui', 'ñor', 'ñora', 'ñorbo', 'ñu', 'ñublado', 'ñublar', 'ñublense', 'ñublino', 'ñublo', 'ñubloso', 'ñuco', 'ñudillo', 'ñudo', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco'],
), (
    ['k', 'ka', 'kabuki', 'kafkiano', 'káiser', 'kaki', 'kaki', 'kalmuko', 'kalmukos', 'kamikaze', 'kamikaze', 'kan', 'kanindeyuense', 'kanindeyuenses', 'kanjobal', 'kanjobal', 'kanjobales', 'kantiano', 'kantismo', 'kappa', 'karaoke', 'kárate', 'karateca', 'karma', 'karst', 'kárstico', 'kart', 'kartismo', 'kastila', 'katipunan', 'katiuska', 'kavakava', 'kayak', 'kazajo', 'kazako', 'kebab', 'kéfir', 'kelvin', 'kendo', 'keniano', 'keniata', 'kerigma', 'kermes', 'kermés', 'kerosén', 'kétchup', 'kevlar', 'kibutz', 'kif', 'kiko', 'kikuyo', 'kiliárea', 'kílim', 'kilo', 'kilobyte', 'kilocaloría', 'kilociclo', 'kilográmetro', 'kilogramo', 'kilogramo', 'kilohercio', 'kilolitro', 'kilometraje', 'kilometrar', 'kilométrico', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', 'kilómetro', 'kilopondio', 'kilotón', 'kilovatio', 'kilovoltio', 'kimono', 'kinder', 'kindergarten', 'kinesiología', 'kinesiología', 'kinesiológico', 'kinesiólogo', 'kinesioterapia', 'kinesioterápico', 'kínésis', 'kinesiterapia', 'kinesiterápico', 'kion', 'kiosco', 'kiosquero', 'kipá', 'kirguís', 'kirguiso', 'kirguiz', 'kirguizio', 'kirguizo', 'kiribatiano', 'kirie', 'kirieleisón', 'kirsch', 'kit', 'kitsch', 'kivi', 'kívnoic', 'kiwi', 'klistrón', 'koala', 'kodzito', 'kohl', 'kohol', 'koiné', 'kopek', 'kosovar', 'krausismo', 'krausista', 'kremlin', 'kremlinología', 'kremlinólogo', 'kril', 'kriptón', 'kris', 'kufiya', 'kurchatovio', 'kurdo', 'kuwaití'],
    ['k', 'ka', 'kabuki', 'kafkiano', 'káiser', 'kaki', 'kaki', 'kalmuko', 'kalmukos', 'kamikaze', 'kamikaze', 'kan', 'kanindeyuense', 'kanindeyuenses', 'kanjobal', 'kanjobales', 'kanjobal', 'kantiano', 'kantismo', 'kappa', 'karaoke', 'kárate', 'karateca', 'karma', 'karst', 'kárstico', 'kart', 'kartismo', 'kastila', 'katipunan', 'katiuska', 'kavakava', 'kayak', 'kazajo', 'kazako', 'kebab', 'kéfir', 'kelvin', 'kendo', 'keniano', 'keniata', 'kerigma', 'kermes', 'kermés', 'kerosén', 'kétchup', 'kevlar', 'kibutz', 'kif', 'kiko', 'kikuyo', 'kiliárea', 'kílim', 'kilo', 'kilobyte', 'kilocaloría', 'kilociclo', 'kilográmetro', 'kilogramo', 'kilogramo', 'kilohercio', 'kilolitro', 'kilometraje', 'kilometrar', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', 'kilopondio', 'kilotón', 'kilovatio', 'kilovoltio', 'kimono', 'kinder', 'kindergarten', 'kinesiología', 'kinesiológico', 'kinesiólogo', 'kinesiología', 'kinesioterapia', 'kívnoic', 'kínésis', 'kinesioterápico', 'kinesiterapia', 'kinesiterápico', 'kion', 'kiosco', 'kiosquero', 'kipá', 'kirguís', 'kirguiso', 'kirguiz', 'kirguizio', 'kirguizo', 'kiribatiano', 'kirie', 'kirieleisón', 'kirsch', 'kit', 'kitsch', 'kivi', 'kiwi', 'klistrón', 'koala', 'kodzito', 'kohl', 'kohol', 'koiné', 'kopek', 'kosovar', 'krausismo', 'krausista', 'kremlin', 'kremlinología', 'kremlinólogo', 'kril', 'kriptón', 'kris', 'kufiya', 'kurchatovio', 'kurdo', 'kuwaití'],
    ['k', 'ka', 'kabuki', 'kafkiano', 'káiser', 'kaki', 'kaki', 'kalmuko', 'kalmukos', 'kamikaze', 'kamikaze', 'kan', 'kanindeyuense', 'kanindeyuenses', 'kanjobal', '%kanjobales', 'kanjobal', '&kanjobales', 'kantiano', 'kantismo', 'kappa', 'karaoke', 'kárate', 'karateca', 'karma', 'karst', 'kárstico', 'kart', 'kartismo', 'kastila', 'katipunan', 'katiuska', 'kavakava', 'kayak', 'kazajo', 'kazako', 'kebab', 'kéfir', 'kelvin', 'kendo', 'keniano', 'keniata', 'kerigma', 'kermes', 'kermés', 'kerosén', 'kétchup', 'kevlar', 'kibutz', 'kif', 'kiko', 'kikuyo', 'kiliárea', 'kílim', 'kilo', 'kilobyte', 'kilocaloría', 'kilociclo', 'kilográmetro', 'kilogramo', 'kilogramo', 'kilohercio', 'kilolitro', 'kilometraje', 'kilometrar', 'kilométrico', '%kilómetro', 'kilométrico', 'kilómetro', '&kilómetro', 'kilopondio', 'kilotón', 'kilovatio', 'kilovoltio', 'kimono', 'kinder', 'kindergarten', 'kinesiología', '%kinesiológico', '%kinesiólogo', 'kinesiología', '&kinesiológico', '&kinesiólogo', 'kinesioterapia', '%kívnoic', '%kínésis', 'kinesioterápico', '&kínésis', 'kinesiterapia', 'kinesiterápico', 'kion', 'kiosco', 'kiosquero', 'kipá', 'kirguís', 'kirguiso', 'kirguiz', 'kirguizio', 'kirguizo', 'kiribatiano', 'kirie', 'kirieleisón', 'kirsch', 'kit', 'kitsch', 'kivi', '&kívnoic', 'kiwi', 'klistrón', 'koala', 'kodzito', 'kohl', 'kohol', 'koiné', 'kopek', 'kosovar', 'krausismo', 'krausista', 'kremlin', 'kremlinología', 'kremlinólogo', 'kril', 'kriptón', 'kris', 'kufiya', 'kurchatovio', 'kurdo', 'kuwaití'],
), (
    ['a', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'ábaco', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'ábax', 'aceite', 'aceite', 'ancianos', 'ár', 'arquitrabe', 'arquitrabe'],
    ['a', 'ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'abadía', 'ábaco', 'ábax', 'arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe'],
    ['a', '$ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', '$ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', '$aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', '$abadía', 'ábaco', '$ábax', '$arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe'],
)]
```

First example:

```py
a, b, expected = examples[0]
out = list(merge(a, b))

>>> out[:4] + ['...'] + out[-4:]
['ñ', 'ña', '&ña', 'ñácara', '...', 'ñudoso', 'ñurdo', 'ñuto', 'ñuzco']
```

We can also check for differences:

```py
a, b, expected = examples[0]

>>> {i: f'{x} != {y}' for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(merge(a, b), expected)) if x != y}
{65: '&ñongo != %ñoña', 66: '%ñoña != &ñongo'}
```

**Note**: we see 56 differences between  `expected` and our result in `examples[1]`, and 13 differences for `examples[2]`. In the former case, we notice that our solution has a lower number of "out-of-order" elements:

```py
a, b, expected = examples[1]
out = list(merge(a, b))
>>> sum(x[0] in '&%' for x in out), sum(x[0] in '&%' for x in expected)
(10, 12)
```

We also see that, while having 56 differences with the expected result, the Levenshtein distance between the two solutions is only 15:

```py
from textdistance import levenshtein

a, b, expected = examples[1]
out = list(merge(a, b))

>>> levenshtein.distance(out, expected)
15
```

It is also interesting to see that, in this specific case, our solution has just 1 more out-of-sequence elements than the Levenshtein distance between `a` and `b`:

```py
>>> levenshtein.distance(out, expected)
9
```

As for `examples[2]`, we note that the result contains `'$'` words that seem inconsistent with the problem statement.

#### Speed

```py
%timeit list(merge(a, b))
29.1 µs ± 33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Larger example:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import Counter

n, m = 100_000, 4
random.seed(0)
a = [''.join(random.choices(ascii_lowercase, k=m)) for _ in range(n)]
b = a.copy()
random.shuffle(b)

# check that some elements are indeed repeated
>>> Counter(a).most_common(1)
[('slfn', 5)]

# now
%timeit list(merge(a, b))
246 ms ± 11.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```